# How to disable secure renegotiation on Port 465 in Postfix

Tags: security, ssl, postfix

How to disable secure renegotiation on Port 465 in Postfix? I have disabled it on port 25 and 587 using `tls_ssl_options` directive. But I am unable to find a solution to disable it on port 465.

My 465 config:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Comment: What happens if you use this option with port 465? How do you even have postfix configured with this port?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i have provided config.

Comment: I cannot see that you use the `tls_ssl_options` option in this command.

Comment: How do I use it there?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how do I use it there. It does not have the SMTPD prefix

Comment: Try to use it as `-o tls_ssl_options= ...` then

Comment: @SteffenUllrich no it is not working

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a usable error description. What exactly did you try, what was your expectation, how did you test your expectation, what happened instead.

Comment: If you did not get a satisfying answer I suggest you ask on postfix-users mailing list: http://www.postfix.org/lists.html . Postfix authors actively participate in that list, so you can get authoritative answer :).

Comment: @raj, hmm... I will try asking there... Maybe I can find already asked questions there.